# Splice removing wrong object from ng-repeat in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm listing an array of names in my view like this:

```
<div class="checkbox col-md-3" ng-repeat="staff in stafflist | orderBy: 'name'">
  <div class="checkboxinner">

    <button class="btn btn-staff form-control" 
            ng-show="!staff.chosen" 
            ng-click="pushStaff(staff)">
               {{staff.name}}
    </button> // visible when unselected, invisible when selected 

    <button class="btn btn-primary form-control" 
            ng-show="staff.chosen" 
            ng-click="unpushStaff(staff, $index)">
               {{staff.name}}
    </button> // visible when selected, invisible when unselected

  </div>
</div>
```

The first button triggers this function, adding the object into the array and being replaced with another button (different color, same content) that is supposed to act as a toggle. This function works perfectly.

```
$scope.paxlist = [];

$scope.pushStaff = function (staff) {
    staff.chosen = true;

    $scope.paxlist.push(
        {
            name: staff.name
        }
    );
    console.log($scope.paxlist);
};
```

Basically, when I click I add the object, when I click again, I remove it. Here's the remove function:

```
$scope.unpushStaff = function (staff, $index) {
    staff.chosen = false;

    var index=$scope.paxlist.indexOf(staff)
    $scope.paxlist.splice(index,1);   

    console.log($scope.paxlist);
}
```

My problem is that the **unpushStaff() will indeed remove an item, but not the item I clicked to remove**, but another one.

What am I missing?

Maybe the ng-show is messing with the $index?

Comment: I see `paxlist` in the controller and `stafflist` in the template. What is the connection between the 2?

Comment: @deitch in the template I list all the items from stafflist, I want to then be able to select some of them and add them to another array (paxlist).

Comment: Oh so the template is for picking from stafflist and adding/removing from a separate paxlist? What are you seeing when you do `unpushStaff()`? Which item is being removed?

Comment: Oh, I just figured it out.

Comment: For instance, I select **a**,**b** and **c**. Then I unselect **b** and paxlist will remain with `[a, b]` instead of `[a,c]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `staff` entry in `stafflist` and the entry in `paxlist` are not identical. Based on your template below:

```
    <button class="btn btn-staff form-control" 
        ng-show="!staff.chosen" 
        ng-click="pushStaff(staff)">
           {{staff.name}}
    </button> // visible when unselected, invisible when selected
```

It is clear that each `staff` entry in `stafflist` is some sort of object that has at least one attribute `name` and another `chosen`.

When you push onto `paxlist`, you are creating a **new** object that looks like:

```
$scope.paxlist.push(
    {
        name: staff.name
    }
);
```

This is fine. **But** when you then come to remove it, you are looking for it by:

```
    var index=$scope.paxlist.indexOf(staff)
```

where `staff` is the object *in stafflist*! Of course, that object does not exist in paxlist - a separate object you derived above in `paxlist.push()` is - and so `indexOf()` is returning `-1`, leading `splice()` to remove the last item on `paxlist`.

Comment: I actually was starting to think in the same direction. But how do I fix it??

Comment: A bunch of ways. The simplest is probably to push the actual object `staff` onto paxlist. If it is the actual object (not another object whose properties happen to match), then `indexOf` will work. Else you will need to search through it one by one (which is all indexOf does anyways). There are some nice tools for this in lodash

Comment: Answers like this are the ones that make me actually learn something : )

Comment: So is figuring them out and writing them. That's actually why I spend my time on here. :-) Use it well.